# OpenGL draw every n vertex

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

I am working on writing an application that contains line plots of large datasets.

My current strategy is to load up my data for each channel into 1D vertex buffers.

I then use a vertex shader when drawing to assemble my buffers into vertices (so I can reuse one of my buffers for multiple sets of data)

This is working pretty well, and I can draw a few hundred million data-points, without slowing down too much.

To stretch things a bit further I would like to reduce the number of points that actually get drawn, though simple reduction (I.e. draw every n points) as there is not much point plotting 1000 points that are all represented by a single pixel)

One way I can think of doing this is to use a geometry shader and only emit every N points but I am not sure if this is the best plan of attack.

Would this be the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this much simpler by adjusting the stride of all vertex attributes to N times the normal one.

Comment: Am I able to do this by just calling glVertexAttribPointer again just after binding to the vbo for drawing. I have tried increasing stride by 1000 times but see no noticeable increase in FPS.

Comment: @Hugoagogo then your bottleneck isn't the amount of points you draw, (100 million isn't that much for modern hardware)

Comment: I know this is a whole new question, but any ideas on where to poke around and start. Also I thought 2gb of vertex data was getting on the large side.

Comment: Also before I accept, I could not find any information on the maximum stride, do you know this.